# What is wrong with this transparent WinAPI label code?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Hi I have a class to create label with WinAPI. Label is created, however after text changing new text is draw above previous-one, I want to ask if someone can notice mistake which leads into such behavior.

```
namespace Gui
{
    const String Label::LABEL_CLASS = L"MY LABEL";
    WNDCLASSEX Label::m_wndClass = Label::CreateWndClass();

    Label::Label() : m_text(L""), m_font(NULL), m_managerWindow(NULL), m_labelWindow(NULL), m_x(0), m_y(0)
    {}

    Label::Label(const String& text, HFONT font) : m_text(text), m_font(font), m_managerWindow(NULL), m_labelWindow(NULL), m_x(0), m_y(0)
    {}

    Label::~Label()
    {
        if (m_labelWindow != NULL)
            DestroyWindow(m_labelWindow);

        if (m_managerWindow != NULL)
            DestroyWindow(m_managerWindow);
    }

    bool Label::Create(HWND parent, int x, int y, int height, int width)
    {
        m_managerWindow = CreateWindowEx(0, Label::LABEL_CLASS.c_str(), NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, x, y, width, height, parent, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (m_managerWindow == NULL)
            return false;

        m_labelWindow = CreateWindowEx(0, L"STATIC", m_text.c_str(), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_LEFT, x, y, width, height, m_managerWindow, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (m_labelWindow == NULL)
        {
            DestroyWindow(m_managerWindow);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    void Label::SetText(const String& text)
    {
        m_text = text;
        if (m_labelWindow != NULL)
        {
            SetWindowText(m_labelWindow, m_text.c_str());
            InvalidateRect(m_managerWindow, NULL, TRUE);
        }
    }

    void Label::SetFont(HFONT font)
    {
        m_font = font;
        if (m_labelWindow != NULL)
            SendMessage(m_labelWindow, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)m_font, TRUE);
    }

    WNDCLASSEX Label::CreateWndClass()
    {
        WNDCLASSEX m_wndClass = {0};

        if (m_wndClass.cbSize == 0)
        {
            m_wndClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
            m_wndClass.style = CS_NOCLOSE;
            m_wndClass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
            m_wndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
            m_wndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
            m_wndClass.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
            m_wndClass.hIcon = NULL;
            m_wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
            m_wndClass.hbrBackground = NULL;
            m_wndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
            m_wndClass.lpszClassName = Label::LABEL_CLASS.c_str(); 
            m_wndClass.hIconSm = NULL;
        }

        RegisterClassEx(&m_wndClass);
        return m_wndClass;
    }

    LRESULT __stdcall Label::WndProc (HWND window, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
    {
        switch(msg)
        {
            case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
            {
                HDC hdc = (HDC) wp; 
                SetBkMode (hdc, TRANSPARENT);

                return (LRESULT)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
            }
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(window, msg, wp, lp);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're going to need to ask whatever is beneath the label to repaint itself.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What do you mean?

Comment: Exactly what I say. Whenever you need to invalidate the label, you need to invalidate whatever is beneath it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made it transparent, so you have to invalid its parent in

```
    void Label::SetText(const String& text)
```

because the control did not erase it's background any more. You have to save the parent window handle in your create method. And replace the

```
InvalidateRect(m_managerWindow, NULL, TRUE);
```

with something like

```
InvalidateRect(m_parentWindow, NULL, TRUE);
```

you can restrict the invalid rectangle by calling GetClientRect on your label and pass that to InvalidRect on the parent.

Comment: I know this option, however it may not work well if parent is static control window. Because "grandparent" may change brush color and it is possible to have lets say red window with label in blue background, it's just an example.

Comment: If you use transparency you have always to paint from your root to the latest child. No other way. As you already defined a class for label, you can also pass a parentobject instead of a handle. Calling a Method to a parent can than lead to a call to it parent. That is the way I resolved that problem in my graphic engine first.